# Hide class if they have parent class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sharepoint-2013

SharePoint 2013 uses iframes for the popups which causes issues when using a modified masterpage. The iframe has a class of .ms-dlgFrame and the element I am trying to hide is .navbar. I have tried using CSS with,

```
.ms-dlgFrame .navbar {
  display: none;
}
```

but it did not work. Using javascipt I am able to tell if the iframe class exists but when I try to hide the navbar it hides the navbar on the main page instead of the popup. The javascript I am using is,

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName('ms-dlgFrame').length) {
    document.getElementsByClassName('navbar')[0].style.Display='none';
}
```

How can I hide the navbar on the popup but not the main page?

[image]

Comment: you cannot affect elements inside an iframe from outside the iframe. That's one of the reasons to use an iframe: it lives completely isolated from the owning context.

Comment: That's not 100% true, if the iframe is on the same domain as the parent document you can. You need to do through document.frames to access the iframe content as it is a separate document.

Comment: I have added a picture of part of the source I am dealing with. @Diodeus it is all on the same domain and is actually built into sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iframe is a separate document, so the iframe content cannot be treated as a child element, as far as CSS goes. You need to address the iframe content directly.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe) talks about how to do this. Just give your iframe an ID so the jQuery selector will work.

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv").removeClass("hidden");
```